# How should a TSV file be formatted in DRUID?

Tags: hadoop, druid

I am curious how a TSV file should look when we are ingesting data from a local TSV file using DRUID.

**Should it just be like:**

**Please note this is just for testing:**

**quickstart/sample_data.tsv file:**

name    lastname    email    time    Bob    Jones    bobj@gmail.com    1468839687    Billy    Jones    BillyJ@gmail.com    1468839769

**Where this part  is my dimensions:** name    lastname    email
**And this part is my actual data:** Bob    Jones    bobj@gmail.com    1468839687    Billy    Jones    BillyJ@gmail.com    1468839769

```
{
        "type" : "index_hadoop",
    "spec" : {
        "ioConfig" : {
                        "type" : "hadoop",
            "inputSpec" : {
                "type" : "static",
                "paths" : "quickstart/sample_data.tsv"
            }
        },
        "dataSchema" : {
            "dataSource" : "local",
            "granularitySpec" : {
                "type" : "uniform",
                        "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
                        "queryGranularity" : "none",
                        "intervals" : ["2016-07-18/2016-07-18"]
            },
            "parser" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "parseSpec" : {
                    "format" : "tsv",
                    "dimensionsSpec" : {
                        "dimensions" : [
                            "name",
                            "lastname",
                            "email"
                        ]
                    },
                    "timestampSpec" : {
                                 "format" : "auto",
                         "column" : "time"
                    }
                }
            },
            "metricsSpec" : [
                {
                    "name" : "count",
                    "type" : "count"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "added",
                    "type" : "longSum",
                    "fieldName" : "deleted"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I had some questions about my spec file as well since I was not able to find the answers to them on the doc. I would appreciate it if someone can answer them for me :)!

`1)` I noticed in the example spec they added the line "type" : "index_hadoop" at the very top. What would I put for the type if I am ingesting a TSV file from my local computer in the quickstart directory? Also where can I read about the different values I should put for this "type" key in the docs? I didn't get a explanation for that.

`2)` Again there is a type variable in the ioConfig: "type" : "hadoop". What would I put for the type if I am ingesting a TSV file from my local computer in the quickstart directory?

`3)` For the timestampSpec, the time in my TSV file is in GMT. Is there any way I can use this as the format. Since I read you should convert it to UTC and is there a way to convert to UTC during the process of posting the data to the Overlord? Or will I have to change all of those GMT time formats to UTC similar to this: "time":"2015-09-12T00:46:58.771Z".

Answer (score 0):

Druid supports two ways of ingesting batch data

- Hadoop Index Task
- Index Task

The spec you are referring to is of a Hadoop Index Task hence "type" is "index_hadoop" and also ioconfig type is "hadoop".

Here is a sample spec for a index task which can read from local file:
`{
    "type": "index",
    "spec": {
        "dataSchema": {
            "dataSource": "wikipedia",
            "parser": {
                "type": "string",
                "parseSpec": {
                    "format": "json",
                    "timestampSpec": {
                        "column": "timestamp",
                        "format": "auto"
                    },
                    "dimensionsSpec": {
                        "dimensions": ["page", "language"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "metricsSpec": [{
                "type": "count",
                "name": "count"
            }, {
                "type": "doubleSum",
                "name": "added",
                "fieldName": "added"
            }],
            "granularitySpec": {
                "type": "uniform",
                "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
                "queryGranularity": "NONE",
                "intervals": ["2013-08-31/2013-09-01"]
            }
        },
        "ioConfig": {
            "type": "index",
            "firehose": {
                "type": "local",
                "baseDir": "examples/indexing/",
                "filter": "wikipedia_data.json"
            }
        }
    }
}`